# Running average with rxjs 5

Tags: rxjs, average, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs5

*I would like to observe rolling averages with rxjs ^5*

### Half-solution

```
const data$ = Rx.Observable.range(1, 9);
const dataToAverage$ = data$.bufferCount(4, 1);
const movingAverage$ = dataToAverage$.map(arr =>
                       arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur) / arr.length);
```

- The above code works fine, except that the first data array it averages is `1,2,3,4`.
- How could I average `1` and `1,2` and `1,2,3` as well?
- Have a play at https://jsfiddle.net/KristjanLaane/kLskp71j/

Comment: I've updated your solution a bit to make it work with the first 3 numbers https://jsfiddle.net/kLskp71j/12/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
Observable.range(1, 9)
    .scan((acc, curr) => {
        acc.push(curr);

        if (acc.length > 4) {
            acc.shift();
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
    .map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, current) => acc + current, 0) / arr.length)
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

The `scan()` just collects at most 4 items and the `map()` then calculates the average.

```
1
1.5
2
2.5
3.5
4.5
5.5
6.5
7.5
```

Comment: I double-checked the output here https://jsfiddle.net/KristjanLaane/xdcb7jho/. Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

My Apologies for not being a JS coder, here's the answer in C#. I would appreciate someone translating for me.

```
var data = Observable.Range(1, 9);
var dataToAverage =
    data
        .Scan(new int[] { }, (a, x) => a.Take(3).StartWith(x).ToArray())
        .Select(x => x.Average());
```

That gives:

```
1 
1.5 
2 
2.5 
3.5 
4.5 
5.5 
6.5 
7.5
```